# Is any other application known to install TeamViewer?

Tags: macos

I was listing my launchd items the other day to track down a constantly-crashing gpg-agent, and I was perturbed to notice TeamViewer in there. So, I removed it, momentarily not thinking much about it; I downloaded their uninstaller and I uninstalled. I made the mistake of not taking notes of exactly what I saw. So, now I'm wondering if my system was, in fact, compromised. Is there any legitimate reason for TeamViewer to be on a Maverics system when, seemingly, 'uninvited'?

Comment: As noted it needs activation but it is the tool used in various scams see this example where a scammer ended up trying to "support" an ant-malware provider http://blog.emsisoft.com/2014/08/29/what-happens-when-a-tech-support-scammer-cold-calls-a-security-expert/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible since the TeamViewer requires activation.

Typically they would send you a email that you signed with containing the link to activate it.

So you might had the software from somewhere but it was not active.